# Selective bold font on graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am annotating my graph with summary statistics. I'd like to use a **bold** font to quickly draw the user's eyes to the best/worst statistics by group. The highlighted numbers would need to be determined at run-time by the data itself.

Here's an example using the ChickWeight dataset, showing changes in chick weights based on their diet:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Calculate end vs start weights
df <- merge(filter(ChickWeight, Time==21), filter(ChickWeight, Time==0), by=c("Chick", "Diet"))
df$dWeight <- df$weight.x - df$weight.y

# Summary statistics: sd & mean
df.stat <- do.call(data.frame, 
                   aggregate(dWeight ~ Diet, 
                             data=df, 
                             FUN = function(x) c(SD=sd(x), MN=mean(x))))

ggplot(data = df) + 
    facet_grid(Diet ~ .) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth=10, aes(x=dWeight)) + 
    geom_vline(data=df.stat, aes(xintercept = dWeight.MN), color="black") + 
    geom_text(data=df.stat, aes(x=Inf, 
                                y=Inf, 
                                label = sprintf("\nmean = %4.1f\nsd = %4.1f", 
                                                dWeight.MN, dWeight.SD), 
                                hjust=1, 
                                vjust=1))
```

In the graph below, I would want to only highlight the following text:
In group 3, "mean = 229.5" would become "mean = **229.5**"
In group 4, "sd = 43.9" would become "sd = **43.9**"

[image]

Comment: Making bold only part of the text and especially the one that is given by a variable is tricky, looks like you will need something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50768373/1320535.

Comment: @JuliusVainora, that technique would seem to require two `geom_text()` calls. One to print the non-bold text and another to print the bold text, leaving the other parts `phantom()`. I'm not sure how to make that work with `facet_grid()`. 
And I'm totally lost on how to use `expression()`, `bquote()`, `substitute()`, etc. in plotmath. Each attempt gives a new error message which leads to another rabbit hole to chase into.

Answer (score 9):

[image: 1]

If you don't want to [muck around with parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728261/change-geom-text-to-bold-when-parse-true/43728313#43728313) you can add a condition to your plot labels and you'll come quite close.

#### Data

```
df.plot <- df %>%
    # Combine df and df.stat -
    # this also removes the calls to df.stat in your secondary geoms.
    left_join(df.stat, by = "Diet") %>%
    # Add global maximum of MN and global minimum of SD to every row.
    mutate(dWeight.MN.max = max(dWeight.MN),
           dWeight.SD.min = min(dWeight.SD))
```

#### Code

```
ggplot(data = df.plot) + 
    facet_grid(Diet ~ .) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 10, aes(x = dWeight)) + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = dWeight.MN), color="black") + 
    geom_text(aes(x = Inf, 
                  y = Inf, 
                  label = sprintf("\nmean = %4.1f", dWeight.MN), 
                  hjust = 1,
                  vjust = 1,
                  # bold if mean == mean maximum
                  fontface = ifelse(dWeight.MN == dWeight.MN.max, 2, 1))) +
    geom_text(aes(x = Inf, 
                  y = Inf, 
                  label = sprintf("\n\nsd = %4.1f", dWeight.SD), 
                  hjust = 1,
                  vjust = 1,
                  # bold if sd == sd minimum
                  fontface = ifelse(dWeight.SD == dWeight.SD.min, 2, 1))) +
    theme_gray()
```

#### Explanation

With `fontface =` you can make your `geom_text()` *italic* or **bold**. 
The `ifelse()` in the expression checks if the value is equal to the global maximum/minimum and sets the text to bold (`= 2`) if true and leaves it plain (`= 1`) if false.

Comment: using your technique and the `latex2exp` library, I was able to modify the `geom_text` statement to only bold the number like this: `label  = TeX(sprintf(ifelse(df.plot$dWeight.MN==df.plot$dWeight.MN.max, "mean = \\textbf{%4.1f}", "mean = %4.1f"), df.plot$dWeight.MN)))`

Comment: Great work! You should post your approach as an answer and accept it yourself. This way this question will no longer be flagged as "open". See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Selective, partially bold text with facet_grid]

Taking the `ifelse` idea from @Roman, here is a solution using the `latex2exp` library to build a LaTeX string that allows **bold** font changes within the string. `latex2exp` translates the TeX string to a plotmath expression.

Still not perfect and not expandable beyond two lines of text. `latex2exp` [does not appear to support newlines](https://github.com/stefano-meschiari/latex2exp/issues/11), forcing me to use `overset` instead.

Another LaTeX option would be an {n x 1} matrix, but `latex2exp` doesn't support matrices either (run `latex2exp_supported()` to see what LaTeX expressions *are* supported).

Or two separate `geom_text` commands if there was a reliable way of spacing and aligning the text as the user resizes or zooms the plot.

This solution is limited to 2-lines that can only be center-aligned to each other.

**Data**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(latex2exp)

# Calculate end - start weights
df <- inner_join(filter(ChickWeight, Time==21), 
                 filter(ChickWeight, Time==0), 
                 by=c("Chick", "Diet")) %>%
      mutate(dWeight=weight.x-weight.y) %>% 
      select(Chick, Diet, dWeight)

# Summary statistics: sd & mean
df.stats <- df %>% 
            group_by(Diet) %>% 
            summarise(MN=mean(dWeight), SD=sd(dWeight)) %>% 
            mutate(is.max.MN=(MN==max(MN))) %>% 
            mutate(is.min.SD=(SD==min(SD)))
```

**ggplot Command**

```
ggplot(data=df) + 
    facet_grid(Diet ~ .) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth=10, aes(x=dWeight)) + 
    geom_vline(data=df.stats, aes(xintercept = MN), color="black") + 
    geom_text(data=df.stats,
              aes(x=Inf, 
                  y=Inf, 
                  hjust=1, 
                  vjust=1),
              label = TeX(paste("\\overset{mean =", 
                                sprintf(ifelse(df.stats$is.max.MN, "\\textbf{%4.1f}", "%4.1f"), df.stats$MN),
                                "}{sd =",
                                sprintf(ifelse(df.stats$is.min.SD, "\\textbf{%4.1f} $", "%4.1f"), df.stats$SD),
                                "}"
                          )))
```

The `label` for `geom_text` is outside the `aes` function which does not appear to inherit the data namespace.

Also, this ggplot command generates a warning message (`TeX` statement):
*In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'expression’*