# Partly italic label in geom_text in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, italic

I want to include a partly italic text (*p=*0.x) into my graph using geom_text. I found this solution [How do I include italic text in geom_text_repel or geom_text labels for ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528953/how-do-i-include-italic-text-in-geom-text-repel-or-geom-text-labels-for-ggplot?newreg=755bde7c6f314535ab3f0e728e9a6e68)

I tried this:

```
geom_text(parse=TRUE, aes(x=2, y = 104, label=expression(paste(italic("p="),"0.052"))), size=5)
```

this is the output:
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type expression. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Column `label` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list

I'm quite new in R and ggplot2 and most of time have no idea what I'm doing. Could somebody explain me why this doesn't work?

Comment: Could you try to remove `expression`: `label = 'paste(italic("p="),"0.052")'`.

Comment: `label = 'paste(italic("p="),"0.052")'`  
writes paste(italic("p="),"0.052")
`label = paste(italic("p="),"0.052")` 
leads to Error in italic("p=") : could not find function "italic"

Comment: For me this works. Did you set `parse = TRUE` ?

Comment: `geom_text(parse=TRUE, aes(x=2, y = 104, label=paste(italic("p="),"0.052")), size=5)` leads to Error in italic("p=") : could not find function "italic" .

Is it possible the interpretation depends on some other settings somewhere? If I use the expression(paste(italic())) constuct in axis title, there is no problem at all. Do I use the parse in the correct place?

Comment: `label = 'paste(italic("p="),"0.052")'` !

Comment: I used   ggtitle(expression(paste("(",italic("F"),"=41.88, ",italic("P>F"),"<7.8e-9)")))

Comment: I've had similar issues (can't find `italic`, etc.). By combining with another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728261/change-geom-text-to-bold-when-parse-true), I was able to make it work with this expression: 
`label = paste0("  italic(n)==", N)`.
The key appears to be using `==` instead of `=`.